# How to create a USDT wallet from ETH NODE RPC

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, go-ethereum

I am using a ETH full node server (geth) with RPC Server to operate some operations in server side (Generate wallet, send transaction).
I would like to generate USDT wallet for my users but I coud not find any good documentation on this.

Do you know how to create a USDT wallet from ETH NODE RPC ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such concept as "USDT wallet" - you have made up that yourself.

Any Ethereum address can receive any token.